# setNavigationBarHidden - resizing views

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to work with GoogleMaps SDK and I wanted to hide navigation bar when I move the map and reveal it when I stop, so:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}

func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
    print("Will move")
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

What I get combining it with custom UIView as infoWindow of the GMSMarker is pretty strange:

[image: strangeBehavior]

The window also changes size - expands when the navigationBar is hidden and shrink when the bar is being shown.

What might be causing this?

PS I should mention that the mapView is placed in a containerView, which is placed in a Content View (UIView), that is a subview of scroll view (horizontal scroll). This is because I wanted to create a sliding menu.

**EDIT**
This is how it looks like in my storyboard. And the MapViewController reference points directly to another view controller that has a mapView inside it.

[image]

**EDIT2**

Now it looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the navigation bar translucent?

Comment: No, the translucent box is unchecked

Comment: I set it to translucent and the behavior is even more strange. Now I can't see my whole mapView on the screen as part of it is beyond the bottom edge

Comment: There is one thing you need to make sure - when the navigation bar is hidden, you have to make sure that all other views mantain their original sizes. That means that all the views must be under the navigation bar even when the navigation bar is still visible.

Comment: I added a new edit.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I think that your main problem is that your `viewController` is not extended below your `navigation bar`, so you need to put your `viewController` extend edges under top bar to `YES`in the storyBoard or you can use `edgesForExtendedLayout` programmatically

I hope this help you